# How to launch a pop up on the correct answering of a text field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm creating an online game wherein players have to answer questions while closing pop ups. If they answer incorrectly, they are greeted with an alert telling them if they are incorrect. If they answer correctly, they receive a pop up to the next question. I have the incorrect functionality working, but I can't get the pop up if correct bit working. What am I doing wrong? Note that I'm very new to Javascript, so this is almost entirely the code of others.

```
            function Start1(URL1, WIDTH, HEIGHT) {
            windowprops = "left=50,top=50,width=" + WIDTH + ",height=" + HEIGHT;
            preview = window.open(URL1, "", windowprops);
        }


        function doPopup1() {
            url1 = "focus.html";
            width = 500;  // width of window in pixels
            height = 500; // height of window in pixels
            delay = 5;    // time in seconds before popup opens
            timer = setInterval("Start1(url1, width, height)", delay*1000);
        } 

        function doPopup2() {
            url2 = "q1.html";
            width = 500;  // width of window in pixels
            height = 500; // height of window in pixels
            delay = 1;    // time in seconds before popup opens
            timer = setTimeout("Start1(url2, width, height)", delay*1000);
        }        


function checkAnswer (form){
        var Answer = form.Answer.value;
        if (Answer == "2"){
            doPopup2();
        }
        else{
            alert ("Incorrect")
        }
    }
```

```
<body OnLoad="doPopup1();">
```

And then a basic HTML table, but the important part is this:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onClick="checkAnswer(this.form)" />
```

Comment: Have you learned how to use the developer tools yet in your browser? If not, now is a good time :) You'll want to open up the dev tools (usually in the tools menu), navigate to the script tab, and then set a breakpoint on the line  `if (Answer == "2")`. Then walk through your question on your web page and the script will stop at the breakpoint. Then you can check out what the values are.  Or more simply, just add the line `console.log(Answer);` immediately before the `if` statement, go to the Console tab of the dev tools and run through your page. You should see some output to help you debug.

Comment: Hey Bill, Thanks for the help. I did not know about the dev tools before, and they will definitely be very useful in the future. Unfortunately, I didn't find anything amiss by going through those steps. The code progressed past the breakpoint as it should have, and the answer was indeed == 2.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code a little bit based on your last comment and tried this:

```
function Start1(URL1, WIDTH, HEIGHT) {
    console.log('Start1 called:' + URL1);
}

function doPopup2() {
    url2 = "q1.html";
    width = 500; // width of window in pixels
    height = 500; // height of window in pixels
    delay = 1; // time in seconds before popup opens
    timer = setTimeout("Start1(url2, width, height)", delay * 1000);
}

doPopup2();
```

Which in my dev tools leads to the error `Start1 is not defined.` being logged to the console. Generally speaking, calling setTimeout with a string is a very bad idea. You'll want to replace that string with a function instead. We'll use an anonymous function so that we can pass in the appropriate parameters.

```
function Start1(URL1, WIDTH, HEIGHT) {
    console.log('Start1 called:' + URL1);
}

function doPopup2() {
    url2 = "q1.html";
    width = 500; // width of window in pixels
    height = 500; // height of window in pixels
    delay = 1; // time in seconds before popup opens
    timer = setTimeout(function() { Start1(url2, width, height); }, delay * 1000);
}

doPopup2();​
```

A little more cleanup and this should work for you. Make sure you declare variables with `var` otherwise they become global. I'm guessing that's why you have url1 and url2 in places.

```
function showPopup(url, width, height) {
    var windowprops = "left=50,top=50,width=" + width + ",height=" + height;
    return window.open(url, "", windowprops);
}

function doPopup1() {
    var url = "focus.html";
    var width = 500; // width of window in pixels
    var height = 500; // height of window in pixels
    var delay = 5; // time in seconds before popup opens
    return setTimeout(function() {
        showPopup(url, width, height);
    }, delay * 1000);
}

function doPopup2() {
    var url = "q1.html";
    var width = 500; // width of window in pixels
    var height = 500; // height of window in pixels
    var delay = 1; // time in seconds before popup opens
    return setTimeout(function() {
        showPopup(url, width, height);
    }, delay * 1000);
}


function checkAnswer(form) {
    var answer = form.Answer.value;
    if (answer == "2") {
        doPopup2();
    }
    else {
        alert("Incorrect")
    }
}​
```

Comment: Sorry to not respond for so long. I went on vacation. I appreciate the cleanup/javascript lesson (I'm going to have to learn this language at some point), but I'm still having the same issue. For whatever reason, doPopup2 just doesn't seem to be running even when the answer is correctly identified as 2.

Comment: You can see an example of it working at http://jsfiddle.net/EkaZU/. Keep in mind that you might not be seeing the popup since most web browsers automatically block popups these days. (The link uses document.write to test instead of the popup for this reason)